# Max value for Counter type (eg. ows_ID) and does ever ows_ID wrap?

Tags: field-type

The auto-incremented unique (within a list) `ID` (aka `ows_ID`) field is of type `Counter`.

The only "documentation" of SharePoint types I can find is this msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype.aspx

Does anyone know what the max value of a Counter field is (I doubt it's infinity) or even better can point me to full documentation of all the types SharePoint uses?

Also, what happens when the max is reached, will the ID wrap? Does the list stop working?

FWIW I'm interacting with SharePoint via SOAP but the type ranges should be the same as the underlying limits.

Update: just while I'm asking, any real difference between `ows_ID`, and the integer parts of `ows_UniqueId`, `ows_ProgId` and `ows_FSObjType`?

Answer (score 0):

As it does not specify anything else than Integer and this type of reference usually refers to Int32 (signed) in .Net. So i would guess that the max value is 2,147,483,647. And i think you would have other issues in SharePoint if you reach that value on a library or list.

However regarding wraparound, i would guess it will wrap around when passing the value counting up from -2,147,483,646.